# bson.ObjectId in a template

Tags: html, templates, go

I have a struct with a bson.ObjectId type, for example something like this:

```
type Test struct {
     Id bson.ObjectId
     Name string
     Foo string
}
```

I want to render this in an html template

```
{{ Name }} {{ Food }}
<a href="/remove/{{ Id }}">Remove me</a>
```

But this obviously doesn't work since `{{ Id }}` would just return a ObjectId type, is there a way to convert this into a string inside the template?

Or do I have to do this when I pass data to the `template.Execute`?

Comment: Hi, I have come to this particular problem to, do you have found a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `id.Hex()` will return a string representation of the `bson.ObjectId`.

This is also the default behavior if you try to marshal one `bson.ObjectId` to json string.

Comment: How would this work if I'm using this in a template? `Id.Hex()` doesn't seem to be accepted

Comment: @woutr_be try to pass the string when you call `template.Execute`?

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that the `Id` in my struct is defined as a `bson.ObjectId`, so if I use `.Hex()` on it, it won't match the type anymore. Not sure what the solution for that is

Comment: the only solution I found so far was to add a new parameter in my struct `String_id string`, which works fine. Although not sure if it's the best solution.

Comment: @woutr_be Could you please be more specific how to add this `String_id string` ? in the retrieved data structure? won't that influence the result stored in db when insert data with that?

Comment: You should be able to just use {{.Id.Hex}} in the template to call that method. E.g. see https://play.golang.org/p/NfZ-Jv7Ck3. See the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Arguments).

Answer (score 5):

The [bson.ObjectId](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId) type offers a [Hex](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId.Hex) method that will return the hex representation you are looking for, and the [template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template) package allows one to call arbitrary methods on values you have at hand, so there's no need to store that value in duplicity anywhere else as a string.

This would work, for example:

```
<a href="/remove/{{ .Id.Hex }}">Remove me</a>
```

Comment: This is correct. While generating a new Object ID, you could call bson.NewObjectId().Hex() and get the string only - in case you later want to insert that to a database and you use string type _id fields

Answer (score 0):

Things like to work [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1LG1NlFEK-)
Just define dot `.` for your template

```
{{ .Name }} {{ .Food }}
<a href="/remove/{{ .Id }}">Remove me</a>
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work when using it in a loop though `{{ .$value.Rating.Id }}`

Comment: FYI, just using `{{ $value.Rating.Id }}` prints out: `ObjectIdHex("54ce0e86d2b38b9d26000001")` and not the actual string