# mgo convert bson.objectId to string(hex) in html template

Tags: go, mgo, objectid, go-html-template

I know this problem maybe duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262392/bson-objectid-in-a-template). But it hasn't get a satisfied answer till now. And I really want to draw some attention to get a solution as soon as possible. So I beg you not to  close this issue unless you have the solution and answered it in the previous one :-)

I will describe the issue for convince:

I have a data structure that was stored in mongodb, as known, the `_id` of mongodb is a `bson.ObjectId` type, I could retrieve that with sort of like this:

```
type Data struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Content string `bson:"content"`
}
```

Then I got a slice of `Data` by finding with specific query condition, and use that slice in `http/template` to render for front-end view. In order to manipulate every item in the slice, I want to use the `Id` field, but When using that with:

```
{{range $key, $value := .DataSlice}}
  <td>{{$value.Id}}</td>
{{end}}
```

That Only gives a sort of string like `ObjectIdHex("550146d1b51bc1c208d1924d")` instead of `550146d1b51bc1c208d1924d` which is nice and easy to use.

In the [duplicate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262392/bson-objectid-in-a-template). The op have said that He found a way to resolve this by "adding a `Id_String`" to the original data structure. But I really don't know how to do this? Is that mean assign it after retrieval ? Since I use a slice to store the data retrieved, And data in a slice couldn't be changed easily. It will be more complex to do that than do the job in the front-end using jquery. But doing that just depress me with my beloved Go :-(.

So is There a better way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bson.ObjectId in a template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262392/bson-objectid-in-a-template)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [bson.ObjectId](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId) type offers a [Hex](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId.Hex) method that will return the hex representation you are looking for, and the [template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template) package allows one to call arbitrary methods on values you have at hand, so there's no need to store that value in duplicity anywhere else as a string.

This would work, for example:

```
<td>{{$value.Id.Hex}}</td>
```

Comment: Also, while generating a new Object ID, you could call bson.NewObjectId().Hex() and get the string only - in case you later want to insert that to a database and you use string type _id fields.

Answer (score 0):

you also can define struct as follows

```
type Data struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,"`
    Content string `json:"content" bson:"content"`
}
```

Then you can use `<td>{{$value.Id}}</td>` when templating html